# PHP Api - Results/Array question

Tags: php, arrays, api

I have been looking around for PHP tutorials and I found a very detailed one that have been useful to me.

But now, I have a question. The results showed by the API are stored into a $results array. This is the code (for instance):

```
$fetch = mysql_fetch_row($go);
$return = Array($fetch[0],$fetch[1]);    
$results = Array(  
    'news' => Array (  
        'id'    => $return[0],  
        'title' => $return[1]  
    ));
```

My question is.. I want to display the last 10 news.. how do I do this? On normal PHP / mySQL it can be done as:

```
    while($var = mysql_fetch_array($table)) {
    echo "do something"
 }
```

How can I make it so the $results can print multiple results?

I have tried like:

```
while($var = mysql_fetch_array($table)) {
    $results = Array(  
        'news' => Array (  
            'id'    => $return[0],  
            'title' => $return[1]  
        )); 
 }
```

But this only shows me one result. If I change the $results .= Array(...) it gives error.

What can I do?

Thanks!

**Edit**

My function to read it doesn't read when I put it the suggested way:

```
function write(XMLWriter $xml, $data){
                            foreach($data as $key => $value){
                                    if(is_array($value)){
                                            $xml->startElement($key);
                                            write($xml, $value);
                                            $xml->endElement();
                                            continue;
                                    }
                                    $xml->writeElement($key, $value);
                            }
                    }
                    write($xml, $results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$results[] = Array(  
        'news' => Array (  
            'id'    => $return[0],  
            'title' => $return[1]  
        ));
```

That should do it.

If you are familiar with arrays, this is the equivalent of an [array_push();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array. The length of array  increases by the number of variables pushed. Has the same effect as:

```
<?php
$array[] = $var;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to add elements to an array:

```
$results = array();

while($var = mysql_fetch_array($table)) {
    $results[] = Array(  
        'news' => Array (  
            'id'    => $var[0],  
            'title' => $var[1]  
        )); 
    }
}
```

You can then loop through the `$results` array. It's not an optimal structure but you should get the hang of it with this.

Comment: The cool thing about using `$var[] =` is that it simply grabs the next highest key.

Comment: I think `$results[] = Array ( 'id' => $var[0], 'title' => $var[1]);` (or even `$results[$var[0]] =  $var[1]`) would be more appropriate. Otherwise you create unnecessary nested arrays.